# how can i sendkeys on hide password in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, junit, magento2, junit4

[image]

Passwords cannot be entered via sendkeys.
There is no error. It is passed without input.
ID is entered normally.

How can I enter my password automatically?

```
            driver.findElement(By.id("mbrId")).click();Thread.sleep(3000);      
            driver.findElement(By.id("mbrId")).sendKeys("dkflrnen");Thread.sleep(3000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("mbrPwd")).click();Thread.sleep(3000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("mbrPwd")).sendKeys("637263");Thread.sleep(3000);
```

Comment: can you provide the HTML markup for this login section?

Comment: @rieckpil how check provide the HTML markup?

Comment: What do you mean with 'cannot be entered via sendkeys'? Do you get any exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing its attribute value:

```
    public void setAttribute(WebElement element, String attributeName, String attributeValue) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute(arguments[1], arguments[2]);",
                element, attributeName, attributeValue);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try **Apache Base64 class** to encode and decode you password accordingly.

> WebElement pwd = driver.findElement(By.id("id of password"));
>
> byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64("Password".getBytes());
> System.out.println("encodedBytes "+ new String(encodedBytes));
>
> byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encodedBytes);
> System.out.println("decodedBytes "+ new String(decodedBytes));
>
> pwd.sendKeys(new String(encodedBytes));